# Cannot verify manually the calculations by tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy

The example in tensorflow site.

```
y_true = [0, 1, 0, 0]
y_pred = [-18.6, 0.51, 2.94, -12.8]
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
bce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
0.865
```

as far as i know BinaryCrossentropy is

```
loss = y_true * log(y_pred) + (1 - y_true) * log(1 - y_pred)

0 * log(2.94) + (1 - 0) * log(1 - 2.94)

log(1 - 2.94)

log(-1.94) ????
```

it is impossible to calculate

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but notice in the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/backend.py#L5295), `y_pred` or `output` in that case is clipped to be between a very small epsilon value and 1 minus this epsilon value `1e-7`:

```
...
  output = tf.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)

  # Compute cross entropy from probabilities.
  bce = target * tf.math.log(output + epsilon())
  bce += (1 - target) * tf.math.log(1 - output + epsilon())
...
```